# Where should I ask PyMol questions?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

PyMol is a molecule visualization program that can produce nice pretty pictures of biological macromolecules.  There seem to be a couple sites that a question regarding this software could go:

- [Chemistry](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/) (I've received no answers or comments on [a question there](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/592/how-can-i-update-a-map-mesh-and-coordinates-in-a-pymol-session-file))
- [Biology](https://biology.stackexchange.com/) (the [community](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/732/how-do-i-get-the-current-camera-position-in-pymol-so-i-can-reuse-it-in-scripts) [seems](https://biology.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/115/questions-about-programming-tweaking-using-biological-software) [split](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/2088/turn-off-multithreading-in-pymol) on them)
- [Computational Science](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/) (such questions aren't about the "[computational methods used](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/faq)")

Comment: [We allow them on chem](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/73/are-software-questions-on-topic), maybe it didn't get enough attention?

Answer (score 2):

While not on the official Stack Exchange network, [BioStar](http://www.biostars.org/) has a good community of people asking and answering bioinformatics questions. I see that others [have asked PyMol questions there](http://www.biostars.org/search/?q=pymol). At one point, there was a discussion about rolling BioStar into the [Bioinformatics Area51 proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/6729/bioinformatics) to bring it into Stack Exchange.

Comment: A mod, suggesting a **non** SE site?! O the travesty. What has this world come to?

Comment: That's pretty much the way it *should* be, isn't it? After all, it's about the *best* resource, not necessarily the best *StackExchange* resource.

Answer (score 0):

I am surprised you didn't consider [Superuser](http://superuser.com). Yes, it's an application used only by a small, specialized audience, but it's an application nonetheless, and that's where application questions go. Even questions like "How do I print from Visual Studio" get routed there, as they're about using an application rather than about programming *per se.*

Comment: Mmmyeah, true, but if it's specialized biochemistry knowledge (or whatever the field is called) that he's asking about, it doesn't really feel like a good fit on Superuser.